# Retrieve/save DWORD from data segment 8086

Tags: assembly, cpu, masm, x86-16, tasm

I have a problem to solve, and I got to the point where I don't know what else I could try. So I have this data segment:

```
data segment
    a db 12h, 34h, 56h, 78h, 9Ah
    b dd 2 dup(?)
data ends
```

What I'm trying to make is to code it in such way that b will have the value exactly like a has it, meaning:

```
b dd 12345678h, 9A000000h
```

Now, the part where I got stuck.
This is for the 8086 CPU, and the data is stored/retrieved using the little endian technique. The high byte from the data segment, is saved into the high byte of a register AX for example, and low byte from DS is saved into the low byte of the register AX.

What I've tried:

```
lea si, a    ; load offset of a into si
lea di, d    ; load offset of d into di
mov cx, 2    ; initialize counter with 2

repeta:
mov dx, [si] ; copy the data starting the offset si to dx
             ; would be cool to get the dword at offset si
             ; into DX:AX, but looks like it doesn't

mov [di], dx ; reverse it into the other variable d
             ; and save DX:AX to offset di
inc si
inc di
loop repeta  ; cx!=0 go to repeta
```

First of all, I am not sure if the code needs to be changed on the way or not, but I could get the data from the offset si, in little endian and also big endian, by getting the values into the DL, DH 8-bit registers (so that shouldn't be a problem).

The problem is that I don't know how I could get the doubleword starting at offset a, to the registers (DX:AX) for example, since they are usually used for this type of things. My current code, gets only a word into DX all the time, but AX remains unchanged.

So the question would be, how to retrieve into two registers a dword from the data segment, in such fashion, that I am able to also save it back in the data segment as a doubleword.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use additional instruction to accomplish this.

`mov ax,[si+2]`

Answer (score 1):

> So the question would be, how to retrieve into two registers a dword from the data segment, in such fashion, that I am able to also save it back in the data segment as a doubleword.

```
lea     si, a
mov     ax,[si]
mov     dx,[si+2]
```

Hereafter DX:AX contains the dword.

> Also, if somebody that knows, coud comment: Related to this question,
>   I guess you can't load a dword directly into two registers like I
>   thought, in otherwords (`lea dx, a` will never take the dword into
>   DX:AX, or otherwise `lea ax, a` will never take a dword into AX:DX). If
>   I'm wrong plese correct me.

You are correct to say that `lea dx, a` will never take the dword into DX:AX but the reason is that LEA does not treat the data stored at an address but rather the address itself.
Both `lea dx, a` and `lea ax, a` put the address of the *a* label in a register.

> I guess you can't load a dword directly into two registers like I
>   thought

There actually exist 2 instructions in 8086 assembly that do just that! LDS and LES. I'll use the latter to show you how it is used.

```
lea     si, a
push    es
les     ax,[si]
mov     dx,es
pop     es
```

Hereafter DX:AX contains the dword.

This is obviously much slower than two separate loads, but is atomic with respect to interrupts on the same CPU.  (i.e. if you're reading a dword that could be modified by an interrupt-handler, an interrupt between two separate `mov` loads could cause "tearing", but `les` either happens before or after an interrupt).

Answer (score 0):

This code shows how to place values in 'b' based on values in 'a', 
expected to get b dd 12345678h, 9A000000h

```
 .model small
.stack  100h
.data
a   db 12h, 34h, 56h, 78h, 9Ah
b   dd 2 dup(?)

.code
main    proc
mov  ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov cx, 4
mov si, offset a
mov di, offset b+3

m1: mov al, [si]
mov [di], al
inc si
dec di
loop    m1

mov si, offset a+4
mov di, offset b+7
mov al, [si]
mov [di], al
dec di
mov byte ptr [di], 0
dec di
mov byte ptr [di], 0
dec di
mov byte ptr [di], 0

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
main    endp
end main
```

Comment: Can you explain how the code solves the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your biggest problem is that the value you're looking for in `b` is NOT the same as `a`.  x86 is little-endian, `memcpy` from `a` to `b` (or any other byte-at-a-time copy without byte-swapping) would actually produce:

```
a   db 12h, 34h, 56h, 78h,   9Ah, 0,0,0  ; added padding 

b   dd 78563412h,            0000009Ah
```

Your `b  dd 12345678h, 9A000000h`  has the first dword endian-swapped, and the 5th byte of `a` as the MSB of the 2nd dword in `b`, not the LSB.

Copying 5 bytes from a to b leaves the last 3 bytes of `b` uninitialized.  (In Unix, .bss space is zero-initialized.  I assume this happens for `dup(?)` space in MASM/TASM, but if not, whatever garbage was there before will still be there.)

If you copy 8 bytes from a to b, the three bytes after the `9A` will be read from the start of `b` if they end up in the same section (rather than `b` going into bss.  Perhaps this is why you used an `org` directive to separate them in your answer.

---

If you don't have any special reason to want to copy a dword all at once, then in 8086 code you should just use [`rep movsw`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/REP:REPE:REPZ:REPNE:REPNZ.html), or normal `mov` instructions, like

```
mov   ax, [a]          ; If your addresses are static, might as well just use
mov   dx, [a+2]        ; absolute addressing, esp in 16bit code where it's only 2B


mov   [b], ax
mov   [b+2], dx
```

Note that your loop with `si` and `di` only increments them by 1, but you load/store two bytes.  Unaligned overlapping loads/stores work, but you're doing redundant work.

---

For your case, you have 5 bytes to copy.  You could use [`rep movsb`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/REP:REPE:REPZ:REPNE:REPNZ.html) with `cx=5`.  8086 of course doesn't support `movsd` or `movsq`, and `rep` startup overhead makes it inefficient for small copies.

---

#### If you do care about doing both loads at once, e.g. from a dword that an interrupt handler can modify:

On a single-core CPU, we don't have to worry about memory being modified by other concurrent threads.  However, an interrupt (maybe triggering a context-switch to another thread) could arrive between any two instructions, but *not* in the middle of a single instruction.  (This is the big difference between single-core atomicity and multi-core: on a multi-core).

So, **if** you're loading a dword that can be modified asynchronously (e.g. by an interrupt handler), and you want to load both halves of it at once, you need to get both halves with a single instruction.

**Do not use this if you're just writing normal single-threaded programs without interrupt handlers**.

One way is with Sep Roland's `les` trick (see his answer), but that leaves `ES` temporarily set to something weird, which might be a problem depending on your interrupt handler.

Another way uses the x87 FPU (not guaranteed to exist on 8086), but you can use it to copy in 32 or 64-bit chunks.  e.g.

```
fild   dword ptr [a]    ; load 32bits as an integer
fistp  dword ptr [d]    ; store as the same integer
; also works with qword ptr

; or store to the stack and then load into dx:ax with two mov instructions
; your own stack memory is private, so you don't need atomic ops there
```

x87's internal 80-bit FP format can exactly represent every 64-bit integer, so this works on any possible bit-pattern.  (`fld`/`fstp` wouldn't, because `fld` requires a valid IEEE double-precision floating point representation, unlike `fild`.)

Even on 8086, it will be atomic with respect to interrupts.  `fild dword` is atomic for aligned loads on 486 and later hardware.

[gcc actually uses this](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B14+-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-verbose-asm+-O3+-march%3Di586+-mno-sse+-m32',source:'%23include+%3Catomic%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Astd::atomic%3Cuint64_t%3E+g64%3B%0A%0Avoid+foo()+%7B+g64.store(2,+std::memory_order_relaxed)%3B+%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) to implement C++11 `std::atomic<uint64_t>` loads/stores in 32-bit mode (since the ISA guarantees that [naturally-aligned loads/stores of 64-bit and smaller values are atomic, on P5 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic/36685056#36685056)).

gcc used to [bounce `std::atomic<double>` values around with fild/fstp](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71245) when SSE2 wasn't available, but that was fixed after I reported it.  (I noticed the issue while answering [Deoptimizing a program for the pipeline in Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361145/deoptimizing-a-program-for-the-pipeline-in-intel-sandybridge-family-cpus/37362225#37362225))

See [Agner Fog's Optimizing Assembly guide](http://agner.org/optimize/) for other useful tricks.  (And also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki).

Comment: A FILD/FISTP would be about an order of magnitude slower than two pairs of 16-bit MOVs on a 16-bit Intel CPU (eg. '286/'287).

Comment: @RossRidge: updated to point out when this might actually be useful.

Answer (score -1):

I guess I found my own answer.

Here is my code:

```
assume cs:code, ds:data
data segment
    a db 12h, 34h, 56h, 78h, 9Ah, 0BCh
    org 20h                             ; make sure I'm not overwrittin
    d dd 2 dup(11111111h)               ; this will be overwritten
data ends

code segment
start:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax


    lea si, a
    lea di, d
    mov cx, 4

    repeta:
    mov dx, [si]
    inc si
    inc si

    mov [di], dx
    inc di
    inc di

    loop repeta


    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
code ends
end start
```

This works, you can clearly see in the data segment that the doublewords that have the value 11111111h will be overwritten in the DS so that it will look like this (in hex): `12 34 56 78 9A 0BC 0BC 00 00`

**To note:** If the data is already arranged in the DS, you don't have to worry about little endian because, when you take it you take it in "reverse order", but once it's written back, it's set back to it's original form (12 34 not 34 12). With this said, you can do easily **mov dx, [si]**

Also, if somebody that knows, coud comment: Related to this question, I guess you can't load a dword directly into two registers like I thought, in otherwords (lea dx, a will never take the dword into DX:AX, or otherwise lea ax, a will never take a dword into AX:DX). If I'm wrong plese correct me.

Comment: When using little endian, `db 12h 32h 56h 78h` is NOT the same as `dd 12345678h`.  `dd 12345678h` in little endian is equivalent to `db 78h 56h 32h 12h`.  Your assignment wants you to show that you understand little endian vs. big endian and how to convert between the two.

Comment: Well, user user1812076, did you turn in your assignment?  Was that the right way to solve the problem?  And also, about the last thing you are asking, you are right, LEA will only affect the register which was specified as an operand, no other registers.

Comment: This may have solved your problem, but it doesn't answer your question as asked.